# Unable to fetch transaction using transactionId on Local Single Node Testnet eos. What could be the reason?

Tags: transactions, testnet, history, single-node

So I am trying to grab the information for a given transaction from EOS Local Single Node Testnet. No matter what I do it says it can't find the transactionID I pass. The **transactionID ID is the valid** one as I get that after writing data to my smartcontract and I'm able to read that data.
I'm using `cleos get transaction <txId>` from cleos to fetch the transction.
I'm getting this error

```
Error 3040011: The transaction can not be found
Error Details:
Transaction 0dd540e426fcd70281a2e2be80ad77b1a67f54e94c50175aa924886db6c98b48 not found in history and no block hint was given
```

The **history plugin seems to be running**, so why is it seemingly unaware of any TX ID I send it?

Comment: Check if you have traces null or have some data in json data of tx from block ? If tx executed successfully, traces shoud have data. so that we cannot get tx by tx_id, because traces is null and history_plugin parse tx through traces

Answer (score 0):

You need to activate `eosio::history_api_plugin` in your nodeos to find a transaction with its ID, or run command with block hint (the number of the block which contains the transaction) like `cleos get transaction <id> --block-hint <block_num>`.

Comment: It is able to fetch transaction with block hint but I read that block hint is optional, then why am I facing this issue ? I need to fetch transaction with tx_id only, as I don't have block hints of past transactions. What should I do ?

Comment: @AditiB You can replay the blockchain and make sure you have all required plugins enabled before replaying. This can be done using blocks.log or taking a snapshot of running instance. Also, you can use mongodb_plugin to save your history.

Comment: @Vipulw Yes I know this but I'm trying to avoid replay of blockchain as I don't have snapshots. Also mongodb_plugin is deprecated.

Comment: @AditiB Ohh, not even .log file ? And yeah it's deprecated too, I checked it now.

Comment: .log file is there but it many a times isn't that reliable. I've faced issues with that, loss of data is there a few times, hence trying to avoid.

Comment: Basically, nodeos doesn't create an index for making it available to search for a transaction with ID only, so you need an exact block number.